# Use of undeclared type in App development with swift

Tags: swift

I'm trying to learn Swift and I am reading through App. development with swift.  In chapter two it uses this as an example to show how Struct works...

```
struct Shirt {
    var size: Size
    var color: Color
}

let myShirt = Shirt(size: .xl, color: .blue)
```

When I run it in playground I get an error "Swift Compiler Error" Use of undeclared type 'Size" and same for "color". I'm wondering why it doesn't work if its' in the book?

Comment: `Size` and `Color` are not standard Swift enums. They must be defined in the book. Add them to your code before your `Shirt` struct.

Comment: Man ruthless a down vote for a simple question!

Comment: It wasn't me. Not sure why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @rmaddy mentioned in the comments you will need to declare the enums for `Size` and `Color`. Try something like this:

```
enum Color {
    case Blue
}

enum Size {
    case xl
}

struct Shirt {
    var size: Size
    var color: Color
}

let myShirt = Shirt(size: .xl, color: .blue)
```